# SQL Server 2008 R2 String concat using CASE..WHEN in the ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange behavior when using a CASE..WHEN in an ORDER BY clause. Here it is :

```
create table #test(num int,val nvarchar(30))
insert into #test select 1,'VAL1'
insert into #test select 2,'VAL2'
insert into #test select 3,'VAL3'
insert into #test select 4,'VAL4'

declare @TmpLib nvarchar(max)
select @TmpLib=''

SELECT @TmpLib = @TmpLib+ t.val
    FROM #test t
    ORDER BY t.num


select @TmpLib
```

In this case my result is VAL1VAL2VAL3VAL4

But if I change the ORDER BY clause like this

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.num=1 THEN 0 WHEN t.num=2 THEN 98 WHEN t.num>=3 AND t.num<4  THEN 99 ELSE 1 END, t.num
```

Then the result is VAL3.

I don't understand how an ORDER BY clause may affect the concatenation like this. I would expect to have still all my values sorted in my @TmLib variable, no ? 
Of course I could first select my records in a second table to sort them and then do my concatenation but I would prefer to do it once !

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [`SET @local_variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189484.aspx), specifically: "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that... I used to work with a previous ORDER BY clause less complicated, but reading the KB article I guess it could have never work at all !

Comment: It's the problem of these things *seeming* to work for a long time and then breaking when you make a trivial (and seemingly unrelated) change that usually surprises people. If you search for SQL Server Concatenation you should find plenty of better solutions. One of the more popular ones (mis)uses the `FOR XML` functionality.